# Are there T4 templates for Visual Studio that handle CRUD for ViewModels like is done for domain models?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, t4, asp.net-core-scaffolding

Visual Studio already has T4 templates to generate the iCRUD pages for the various Razor pages, but these are built around the input of the domain models.

I would like something similar, except input a ViewModel (to start with, all properties are from a single domain model). Default to using AutoMapper or choose to individually map the Domain Model properties to the ViewModel properties.

For instance, I have a Person domain model with 30+ properties. For a simple company phone book lookup, all I need are a few properties.  If I could create a ViewModel that had only these properties and used a T4 template to create the Index (list) razor pages, that would be done.  Then if the Powers That Be decided they wanted another property; Boom! change the ViewModel, regenerate the Razor page and be done.

This would make minor change requests easy, allow easy prevention of overposting, allow quick-and-dirty changes be done by others, elimination of possible spelling errors, etc.

If I was (much) smarter, I am quite sure the existing templates could be easily modified to handle this.

I was wondering if this was something already created.

thank you for your time.
chuck

Comment: It *feels* that T4 templates are now obsolete. New way is to build Custom template - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates . It seems pretty straightforward to do what your describe

Comment: Figures.  Just when I think I've found a good idea, the entire thing goes away.  I am in the process of reviewing your link.  Thank you vey much for the rapid response.

Comment: You're a software developer; you are asking for "software that writes code" but don't forget if you cannot find it you do have all the necessary powers to create it..

Comment: Good point about roll-my-own. Check out last paragraph in posting. See also that MICROSOFT itself wrote scaffolding code for Visual Studio, so developers don't have to "create it".

Comment: T4 is still useful for some custom stuff tho (generate based on dependency pre, on or post build), but yes, seems like CT is going to take over most scaffolding. There is just no easy or straight forward T4 development experience, and most editors fail to provide that too.

Comment: Tim, thank you for the info. It seems that the T4 scaffolding is still used in the latest MS tutorials. For us beginners, it seemed like a great idea. I'm sure that the pro's would want something more robust.